# Hyperlinks for SVG in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, hyperlink, path

I’m having an issue with adding a pretty complex SVG image with many many paths into my HTML index.page. I edit the SVG image the best I can within Inkscape and it’s own SVG file, but once it comes to adding links to those paths in the SVG, I have to then embed it into my HTML file, which SLOWS things down. Is their anyway I can minimize this issue or even edit and create links to these many paths without doing so within my HTML file. In short, is there a way to add links to my SVG paths without it being in HTML, and then just refer to it in HTML without having to add the entire massive SVG file? Really really could use some help here as I’m not the most expert programmer around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please read about [The <a> SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a)

Comment: Do you think of "links" in the sense of HTML links (click and go there), or of references (show in place)?  Please describe what should be shown. The whole image? Only some paths? Only a region that contains some paths?

Comment: Yes link as in click and go there. I have paths created with images inside them all on Inkscape, and then I need to be able to add the hyperlink to the path inside HTML or something to then make it a clickable image on the website.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that.

```
   <img 
        src="chitchat.svg" 
        height="100"
        width="100" 
    />
```

Comment: So is there a way to add links to the paths within the SVG file that is being referred to? That would be best since it’s a large SVG file and it will slow down my HTML Significantly.

Comment: why to refer to path??

Comment: Because I want the SVG image to be clickable and take you to links that correspond to the path.